# Why is my POST request not working in Node

Tags: node.js, express

I am very very stuck in this "almost there" type of problem. I am new to programming but got along just fine until I came across this issue.

So, I have this POST call to put a new user, which I get from Facebook using Passpost.js, if the "id" does not exist.

Here is the POST call (using "request" module):

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebook.appID,
    clientSecret: config.facebook.appSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'emails', 'birthday', 'location', 'bio', 'likes.limit(100)']
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':profile.id}, function(err, result){
        if(result){
            done(null, result);
        } else {
            request({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/user',
                qs: {id:  'profile.id',},
                method: 'POST',
                json: {
                    fullname:   profile.displayName,
                    profilePic: profile.photos[0].value || '',
                    email:      profile.emails[0].value || '',
                    birthday:   profile._json.birthday || '',
                    location:   profile._json.location.name || '',
                    about:      profile._json.bio || '',
                    likes:      profile._json.likes || ''
                }
            }, function(error, response, body){
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log(response.statusCode, body);
                }
            });

        }
    })


}
)
)
```

I am grabbing the POST call on my router like this:

```
apiRouter.post('/api/user', secureAPIPages, function(req, res, next){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':req.query.id}, function(err, result){
        if(result){
            console.log('User exists already');
        } else {

            var newUser = new userModel({
                profileID   :   res.query.id,
                fullname    :   res.json.displayName,
                profilePic  :   res.json.photos || '',
                email       :   res.json.emails || '',
                birthday    :   res.json.birthday || '',
                location    :   res.json.location || '',
                about       :   res.json.bio || '',
                likes       :   res.json.likes || ''
            });

            newUser.save(function(err){
                console.log('User has been saved');
            })
        }
    })
})
```

I get this from the POST call: 302 undefined (302 being the statusCode and undefined being the body from the POST call in the request module).

This is really a two part question:

**1)** Why is my POST call not working?
**2)** Does my apiRouter.post route look okay?

It may be something very simple but I have spent countless hours to try and debug this but I am really not getting anywhere.

Your help will highly be recommended.

Thanks,
Shayan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `done()` after you added user

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    // ommited
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':profile.id}, function(err, result){
        if(result){
            done(null, result);
        } else {
            request({
                // ommited
            }, function(rErr, rResponse, rBody){
                 //use rResponse or rBody, depends on request package
                 //you must pass new created user to `done` callback
                 done(rErr, rBody); // <== done from passport callback
            });
        }
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That took me a step further but now it's saying my req.body object is undefined. I may lose my mind on this but if you have any suggestions, it'll be highly appreciated. (by the way, req.body is changed from res.json as it was pointed out by QoP in another comment)

Comment: Started working! I was missing the body-parser module to read .body object (duh)!!! Thanks a lot man, I am making your answer as the answer for this as it was this that helped me the most!

Answer (score 2):

The data you submit via request post is in req.body, not in res.json.

this

```
var newUser = new userModel({
                profileID   :   res.query.id,
                fullname    :   res.json.displayName,
                profilePic  :   res.json.photos || '',
                email       :   res.json.emails || '',
                birthday    :   res.json.birthday || '',
                location    :   res.json.location || '',
                about       :   res.json.bio || '',
                likes       :   res.json.likes || ''
            });
```

should be

```
var newUser = new userModel({
                profileID   :   req.query.id,
                fullname    :   req.body.displayName,
                profilePic  :   req.body.photos || '',
                email       :   req.body.emails || '',
                birthday    :   req.body.birthday || '',
                location    :   req.body.location || '',
                about       :   req.body.bio || '',
                likes       :   req.body.likes || ''
            });
```

Comment: That didn't work mate. I have tried that before. Getting the same result unfortunately

Comment: Was missing the body-parser module lol. Thanks a lot for your response and time mate!

Answer (score 2):

What is apiRouter ? 
I hope it is the instance of the express object . As in somewhere you have line like

```
var express = require('express');
var apiRouter = express.Router();
```

With that assumption, the route looks fine enough though advisable to encapsulate your functions in another file . Will help in the segregation of your api layer from the routes some thing like :

```
var controllers = require("../controllers/web");
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controllers.home.landing);
router.get('/collections', controllers.collections.get_all_products_by_store);
router.get('/register', controllers.login.register);
router.get('/login, controllers.login.login_view);
router.post('/store_city_details', controllers.home.store_city_details)
```

Also your POST call is fine too . You're getting a 302 Response from your server :

> HTTP 302. The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of
>   performing URL redirection. An HTTP response with this status code
>   will additionally provide a URL in the location header field. HTTP 302
>   - [Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)

The only piece of your code that doesnt make sense is

```
secureAPIPages
```

You've used a middleware that is sending you the 302 redirect response. Your request isn't even reaching  the endpoint you want it to. 
If it had been returning a 200 StatusOkay you would be sure that your API works. 
But then there's that bit of understanding the request and response object of node.

the line :

```
function( req, res, next) ...
```

you have access to three parameters :

- req : the request object
- res : the response object
- next : Function - Used to transfer control to the next function in the route.

If it is the endpoint of your api use the response object to send back a response to the original post call :

```
collections.get_cart_data = function (req, res) {

  logger.info('[WEBSITE][API] in collections get_cart_data')
  res.json(req.session.selected_products); // sends back a response in json format that is made of the selected_products we received in the request session object
};
```

Your code :

```
var newUser = new userModel({
                profileID   :   res.query.id, // I guess you want the value of the profile id in the request . Use req.query to access query values of the HTTP request
                fullname    :   res.json.displayName, // this is some weird bit of code I just cant wrap my head around..
                profilePic  :   res.json.photos || '', //  res.json is used to send a json response back to the api call  
                email       :   res.json.emails || '', // What you are trying to do is tried to save that value in another object key value pair ?? 
                birthday    :   res.json.birthday || '', // There is no req.json method i am aware of so idk . these should be 
                location    :   res.json.location || '',// req.body . 
                about       :   res.json.bio || '',
                likes       :   res.json.likes || ''
            });

            newUser.save(function(err){
                console.log('User has been saved');
            })
```

there is different req methods used to access the different values sent in the request object. 
For Clarification : The values you pass in your POST/GET call are accessible to you in the request object :

> req.body : Access to body values, used in POST call
>   req.query : Access to query values, used in GET call 
>   req.params : Access to  parameters, used in GET call

So your api should be more like :

```
apiRouter.post('/api/user', secureAPIPages, function(req, res, next){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':req.query.id}, function(err, result){
        console.log("MY REQUEST BODY OBJECT VALUES", req.body) // will show you the object you passed in " json:{} " of your POST call
        console.log("MY REQUEST Query  OBJECT VALUES", req.query) // will show {id:  'profile.id'} Please remove that trailing comma. Really got my ocd
        console.log("MY REQUEST Params OBJECT VALUES", req.params) // would be empty {}
        if(result){
            console.log('User exists already');
            res.send({"errmsg":"User exists already"})//send error response back 
        } else {
            /* Write clean code, define objects separately*/
        var newUserDetails ={
                "profileID"   :   req.query.id, // using req.query here as the qs value in your post call passes a query string appended to the url . used for auth purposes
                "fullname"    :   req.body.fullname, // Notice the use of "" for proper JSON structure. Use Jslint to verify your jsons
                "profilePic"  :   req.body.profilePic || '', // Also notice I have changed the variable names 
                "email"       :   req.body.email || '', // These need to match the key values as provided in POST call . 
                "birthday"    :   req.body.birthday || '', 
                "location"    :   req.body.location || '',
                "about"       :   req.body.about || '',
                "likes"       :   req.body.likes || ''
            }

            var newUser = new userModel(newUserDetails);

            newUser.save(function(err){
                console.log('User has been saved');
                var response = {
                "message" : " User has been saved",
                "user" : newUserDetails
                }
                res.send(response); // will send the reponse object back to your frontend
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: You are right, it should be req.body instead of req.json (QoP mentioned that as well in one of the other comments). However, saving it directly within the code works (like you stated above) but what I am trying to do it make an API server so the stuff I need for POST, GET etc should be handled externally so I can make other clients easily (for iOS, Android etc). But it is not working and except changing the .json to .body, I don't see any other issues and it should work but it isn't. Don't know what I am missing here

Comment: Also, your assumption about apiRouter is correct and secureAPIPages is just a function which redirects the user to a "API not authorised" page if the user doesn't exist. This works on the other GET routes so that should be fine. I have removed it from my debugging as well so that's not the issue - just to further isolate the problem

Comment: It started working! Please see the accepted answer. Highly appreciate your feedback and time. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: To build vs to grow, an age old debate. But I guess once the code works its enough for most people. :)

Comment: Yeah found the root cause. First, I was using res.json (which was wrong) which I changed to req.body. But then, the req.body was coming as 'undefined" which I then looked up to be because I needed the body-parser module (duh)!. So all good now. Thanks